# Legend title in print composer with different font styles

Tags: qgis, printing, layouts

I want to design a layout with print composer where the legend Title has two different font styles in one e.g. " I had it once but can´t *remember*".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't found a way how to format legend titles to allow two different font styles, but remember that it is possible to simply add another label [image] to your image. 
Enable the snapping to grid option and place your layer right next to the legend title. Remember to raise this label object [image], so that it won't be hidden by the legends borders.
You can style this label in any way you want. The result could look like this:

[image]

Nevertheless:
Sometimes it is a lot easier to simply insert the whole Title with a Graphic manipulation program such as GIMP or Photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

As it was announced [here](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog330/#print-layouts) on the last release, it is perfectly possible to add different font styles to the legend items.